# Best way to implement Sockets in Android to build a messaging application

Tags: java, android, sockets, message

I am learning about Socket programming in Android basically to create a simple messaging app for learning purpose.
I have found out a lot of helpful materials online to get started with it. Like [this](https://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/03/27/incorporating-socket-programming-into-your-applications/) one for eg.
However, in the above article, we need to manually enter the server ip address in the client to establish a connection between both of them.
I would like to know whats the best way of making this process automatic?.

One way I thought of was by using GCM. When a device A wants to communicate with device B, A will first send its ip address and port number (where it will be listening for incoming msgs)to B via GCM and B also does the same thing.
Now both the devices know each others ip address and port number on which they are listening, from here onwards they can start communicating with each other.
[Note: I am not considering GCM as a primary way of messaging as I have read in many blogs its not that fast for instant messaging].

This is just a thought. I would like to know what is the best way of doing this for a messaging application. Thanks.